# Fake is not a spy

Tags: unit-testing, sinon

So i have a method that calls an https request. i've successfully stubbed the calls in other tests but this one is beating me an it just won't work.

in my beforeEach i create the stub
in my afterEach i do stub restore

in the test i create four stub calls.

`stub.onCall(0).callsFake((arg1, arg2, arg3, cb, arg5) => {return cb(null, {some object0})
stub.onCall(1).callsFake((arg1, arg2, arg3, cb, arg5) => {return cb(null, {some object1})
stub.onCall(2).callsFake((arg1, arg2, arg3, cb, arg5) => {return cb(null, {some object2})
stub.onCall(3).callsFake((arg1, arg2, arg3, cb, arg5) => {return cb(null, {some object3})`

then after my ACT statement i attempt to assert the stubs are called with the correct parameters

`sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.firstCall, "blah","blah","blah",, sinon.match.any, "blah")
sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.secondCall, "blah","blah","blah",, sinon.match.any, "blah", "blah")
sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.thirdCall, "blah","blah","blah",, sinon.match.any, "blah")
sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.call(3), "blah","blah","blah",, sinon.match.any, "blah"`

Unfortunately my test now reports

AssertError: fake is not a spy

I've console.logs in my code under test and they are reporting my stubs being called.

a call to console.log(stub.callCount) return 1 not 4

if i comment all but the first sinon.assert the test passes.

So my question is what am i doing wrong

I'll post my full setup below

`    describe('Update Redis', () => {
        const balances = {
                "TRTLv2Fyavy8CXG8BPEbNeCHFZ1fuDCYCZ3vW5H5LXN4K2M2MHUpTENip9bbavpHvvPwb4NDkBWrNgURAd5DB38FHXWZyoBh4w": 12000
        }
        const minPayoutLevel = {
                "TRTLv2Fyavy8CXG8BPEbNeCHFZ1fuDCYCZ3vW5H5LXN4K2M2MHUpTENip9bbavpHvvPwb4NDkBWrNgURAd5DB38FHXWZyoBh4w": 10000
        }
        const endpoint1 = '/transactions/prepare/advanced'
        const endpoint2 = '/transactions/send/prepared'

```
    beforeEach(() => {
            stub = sinon.stub(apiInterfaces, 'jsonHttpRequest')
    })

    afterEach(() => {
            sinon.restore()
    })

    it("Should update workers balance, paid ,coin:payments:all and coin.payments.workers:address", () => {
            //ARRANGE
            let error = null

            const endpoint = '/transactions/prepare/advanced'
            const endpoint2 = '/transactions/send/prepared'
            stub.onCall(0)
                    .callsFake(function (host, port, data, callback, path) {
                            return callback(null,  {"transactionHash": "396e2a782c9ce9993982c6f93e305b05306d0e5794f57157fbac78581443c55f","fee": 1000,"relayedToNetwork": false})
                    })
            stub.onCall(1)
                    .callsFake(function (host, port, data, callback, path) {
                            return callback(null, null)
                    })
            stub.onCall(2)
                    .callsFake(function (host, port, data, callback, path) {
                            return callback(null, {"transactionHash": "396e2a782c9ce9993982c6f93e305b05306d0e5794f57157fbac78581443c55f","fee": 1000,"relayedToNetwork": false})
                    })
            stub.onCall(3)
                    .callsFake(function (host, port, data, callback, path) {
                            return callback(null, {
                                    "transactionHash": "396e2a782c9ce9993982c6f93e305b05306d0e5794f57157fbac78581443c55f"
                            })
                    })

            let callback = () => {return}
            //ACT
            coin.processPayments(balances, minPayoutLevel, callback)
            console.log(stub.callCount)
            sinon.assert.calledThrice(stub.jsonHttpRequest)
            sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.firstCall, config.wallet.host, config.wallet.port, '{"destinations":[{"amount":12000,"address":"TRTLv2Fyavy8CXG8BPEbNeCHFZ1fuDCYCZ3vW5H5LXN4K2M2MHUpTENip9bbavpHvvPwb4NDkBWrNgURAd5DB38FHXWZyoBh4w"}],"feePerByte":2,"unlock_time":0,"mixin":3}', sinon.match.any, endpoint1)
            sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.secondCall, config.wallet.host, config.wallet.port, '396e2a782c9ce9993982c6f93e305b05306d0e5794f57157fbac78581443c55f', sinon.match.any, endpoint1, 'DELETE')
            sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.thirdCall, config.wallet.host, config.wallet.port, '{"destinations":[{"amount":11000,"address":"TRTLv2Fyavy8CXG8BPEbNeCHFZ1fuDCYCZ3vW5H5LXN4K2M2MHUpTENip9bbavpHvvPwb4NDkBWrNgURAd5DB38FHXWZyoBh4w"}],"feePerByte":2,"unlock_time":0,"mixin":3}', sinon.match.any, endpoint1)
            sinon.assert.calledWith(stub.call(3), config.wallet.host, config.wallet.port, '{"transactionHash":"396e2a782c9ce9993982c6f93e305b05306d0e5794f57157fbac78581443c55f"}', sinon.match.any, endpoint2)
    })
    })
```

})
`

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and it turned out to be the way I was asserting the call. Maybe you could try something like this (I assumed you were using jasmine or jest, but you could change the `expect()` call to whatever your framework uses): 

`expect(stub.jsonHttpRequest.calledThrice).toBeTruthy();`